# How to read XML xpath in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I am stuck with this task for the past two days and I did not get any clear solution through different articles. So kindly give me a step by step code to retrieve the XPath values present in XML.

My XML is

```
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <int name="sno">1</int>
    <str name="author">J K. Rowling</str>
    <int name="price">29.99</int>
    <str name="subauthor">J K</str>
  </book>
   <book>
    <int name="sno">2</int>
    <str name="author">J K. Rowling</str>
    <int name="price">29.99</int>
    <str name="subauthor">hamilton</str>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

In this XML I need each author, price and subauthor values.
My expected result is:

```
(author-J K. Rowling,price-29.99,subauthor-j k)
```

And then how to get the last value of the subauthor from this XML.

My java code to get this values is not working. Its throws an exception only.

```
public gettheXMLvalues() {
  try {
    NodeList nodeLst1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("doc");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeLst1.getLength(); i++) {
      Node node = nodeLst1.item(i);
      if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element element = (Element) node;
        NodeList nodes = element.getElementsByTagName("//str[@name='author']").item(0).getChildNodes();
        node = (Node) nodes.item(0);
        System.out.println("ELEMETS " + element.getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Author" + node.getNodeValue());
      }
  } catch(Exception e){
    system.out.println("Exception  "+e);
  }
}
```

Kindly give me a solution to get the value of author, price and subauthor of each book.I tried lots of things for getting the result, but unfortunately I did not get the result. Kindly give me the clear solution.

Comment: Post the exception trace

Comment: i don't think the method `getElementsByTagName` accepts Xpath expressions. You could better do something like this
`XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/bookstore/book/int [@name='price']/url");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);` . Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java

Comment: [The Java XPath API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html) on developerWorks

Comment: I need the clear code for my above problem.I need to read the value of author,price of each doc tag.Give me the sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public static ArrayList gettheXMLvalues(Document xmlDocument, String author) throws Exception {

```
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<Element> elementList = xmlDocument.selectNodes("//str[@name='author']");

    if (elementList == null) {
        return result;
    }

    ArrayList<Element> listAuthor = new ArrayList<Element>();

    for (int i = 0; i < elementList.size(); i++) {
        Element el = elementList.get(i);
        if (el.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(author)) {
            listAuthor.add(el);
        }
    }

    if (listAuthor.size() == 0) {
        return result;
    }
    else {
        String authorLine = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < listAuthor.size(); i++) {

            Element element = listAuthor.get(i);

            Element price = (Element)element.getParent().selectSingleNode("./int[@name='price']");
            Element subauthor = (Element) element.getParent().selectSingleNode("./str[@name='subauthor']");

            authorLine = "author-" + author + ",price-" + price.getText() + ",subauthor-" + subauthor.getText();

            result.add(authorLine);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```